# How to create a method for an array class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, methods

Sorry, I know this is programming 101, but I can't find any good documentation...

I have an array, and I want to cast each member as an object and then call them by the name assigned (this would be so much simpler if javascript allowed for non-number index values). For instance:

```
 var things = ['chair', 'tv', 'bed'];
 var costs = ['10', '100', '75'];

 for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
      thing.name = things[i];
      thing.cost = costs[i];
 }

 alert(thing.name('tv').cost);
```

Obviously this isn't the way to do this, but the desired outcome would be an alert that said "100".

I have gotten as far as creating a class that has a method called name which points back to the main object, like so:

```
function thing(name, cost) {
         function name(thename) {
              return this;
         }
this.thingname = name;
this.name = name;
this.cost = cost;
}
```

But this still requires that each object has a unique variable name, which goes against the whole point. What I want is to simply throw all of my array into some generic class and call the values I need by the name.

I know this is probably way to easy to ask here, but I'm stuck!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using the JSON object format? http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Btw, this isn't programming 101, you seem to have that down.  This is just javascript 101, cuz javascript's notion of an object isn't quite like most other languages' (it's way cooler!).

Comment: You say javascript does not allow for non-number index values, but it does! var x; x['imNotaNumber'] = 'hai'; is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use objects?

```
var things = {
  chair: 10,
  tv: 100,
  bed: 75
};
alert(things.chair); // 10
alert(things['tv']); // 100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var stuff = {
    chair: 10,
    tv: 100,
    bed: 75
};
alert(stuff.chair); // alerts '10'
alert(stuff['chair']); // alerts '10'

stuff.house = 100000;
stuff['car'] = 10000;
alert(stuff['house']); // you get the picture...
alert(stuff.car);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just using a dictionary object:

```
var things = {'chair':10, 'tv':100, 'bed':75};
alert(things['chair'])

// if you want to use things['chair'].cost, it'd look more like this:
var things = {'chair': {cost: 10}, 'tv': {cost: 100}, 'bed': {cost: 75}};
```

Answer (score 1):

use Why don't define your arrays as an object like

```
var things = {'chair':10, 'tv':100, 'bed':75}
```

Then you can access prices like properties of an associative array

```
things.chair
```

would give you 10

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try JSON:

like

```
var myArray= {"things": [
                    {"name":"chair","price":"10"},
                    {"name":"tv","price":"100"},
                    {"name":"bed","price":"75"}
             ]};

//now you can use it like this
for(var i=0; i< myArray.things.length; i++)
{
    alert(myArray.things[i].name + " costs " + myArray.things[i].price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this using your original data format (because you have no influence on it) use the following:

```
var things = ['chair', 'tv', 'bed'];
var costs = ['10', '100', '75'];

var associatedThings;

for(i=0,x=things.length;i<x;i++){
    associatedThings[things[i]] = {cost: costs[i]};
}

alert(associatedThings['tv'].cost);
```